# Matplotlib get yticklabel on mouse click

Tags: matplotlib

I have a pretty simple horizontal barchart. (barh)
What I am trying to do is to print the yticklabel when I click a bar. Is this even possible?

Let's say I have the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


plt.rcdefaults()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Example data
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

ax.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center',
        color='green', ecolor='black')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('Performance')
ax.set_title('How fast do you want to go today?')

plt.show()
```

What I would like to do is print  "Jim" whenever I click the coresponding bar on the chart.

Comment: Since bars are in general do not necessarily connected to any yticklabel, you probably want to spend some more words on what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to print the bar height instead?

Comment: I added an edit with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to define a `picker` in the `bar`. Then connect the `pick_event` to a function that finds the index of the corresponding bar in the list of ticklabels you supply.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Example data
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

ax.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center',
        color='green', ecolor='black', picker=True)
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(people)
ax.invert_yaxis()  # labels read top-to-bottom
ax.set_xlabel('Performance')
ax.set_title('How fast do you want to go today?')

def onpick(event):
    if isinstance(event.artist, plt.Rectangle):
        y = people[int(np.round(event.artist.get_y()))]
        print(y)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm!